# Do function at keydown on Right CTRL / VK_RCONTROL

Tags: c#, keyboard, compact-framework

I have a device that has a gun-like grip and a trigger. I want to fire up some function when I press this trigger. When I pull the trigger, it returns **H,RControlKey** at the KeyDown event.

Question is, how do I do a function when that trigger key (H, ControlKey) is pressed?

Comment: A Low Level Keyboard hook? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/toub/archive/2006/05/03/589423.aspx

Comment: Most of these devices have a dedicated SDK that will allow you to create a dedicated object to listen for the trigger state changes.  These work no matter which form or control has focus, and even if your app is minimized.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.RControlKey)
            {
               //your code
            }
```

This also works with other keys like A, B, or shift.